# Build Issue in cordova ios platform 6.0.0 for cordova-plugin-file-transfer ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Tags: ios, cordova

I get the error on ionic cordova build ios command after updating ionic cordova ios platform to 6.0.0.

see more info about the here
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html

I have tried downgrading the cordova-file-transfer plugin to the previous versions but it did not help.... does anyone have the solution...note that I am able to build the project without the cordova-plugin-file-transfer.... I have an ionic 3 project...  All was working in cordova ios version 5.1.1 but had to upgrade the UiWebView deprecation issue... Please help me

More info here
https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

honeos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVDevice.dia -c /Users/user/Desktop/Projects_Joel/appfoldername/platforms/ios/appname/Plugins/cordova-plugin-device/CDVD
evice.m -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedDatanew2/navitusCorporate-ekmztaardnofwbeaswcdxrkqwfcp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/navitusCorporate/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVDevice.o
warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File: Failed to open diagnostics file (in target 'appname' from project 'appname')

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedDatanew2/appname-ekmztaardnofwbeaswcdxrkqwfcp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/navitusCorporate.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVFileTransfer.o /Users/user/Desktop/Projects_Joel/appfoldername/platforms/ios/appname/Plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/CDVFileTransfer.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

(1 failure)
Error: xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).

Comment: Did you find any cause or solution?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you, i have to upgrade the UiWebView and file transfer makes build failed.

Comment: Same issue here. Also upgrading a ionic3 project for the new iOS requirements. Removing plugin lets me build it but that would mean rebuilding the app a bit as well..^

I did see something intresting with regards to cordova-plugin-filetransfer on their site regarding sunsetting the plugin with the new XmlHttpRequest covering the need for this plugin. https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Have not seen any information about this on Ionics page tough..

Comment: The same problem here. I had to remove it from the project to compile.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue after upgrading the cordova-ios 6.1 version. I tried the XmlHttpRequest approach but no luck. Is anyone achieved it?